# Hive drops all the partitions if the partition column name is not correct

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop-partitioning

I am facing a strange issue with hive,
I have a table, partitioned on the basis of dept_key (its a integer eg.3212)
table is created as follows

```
create external table dept_details (dept_key,dept_name,dept_location) PARTITIONED BY (dept_key_partition INT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '~' LOCATION '/dept_details/dept/';
```

Now I have some partitions already added e.g: 1204,1203,1204
When I tried dropping the partition I by mistake typed only `dept_key` and not `"dept_key_partition"` this in turn dropped all my partition
drop query `alter table dept_details drop partition (dept_key=12)`, its a very strange issue which I am facing. Please let me know what can be the probable issue.
Thank you.

Comment: Please show the whole drop partition statement which you used.

Answer (score 0):

From [Hive LanguageManual DDL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-PartialPartitionSpecification)...

> As of Hive 0.14 (HIVE-8411), users are able to provide a **partial
>   partition spec** for certain above alter column statements, similar to
>   dynamic partitioning *(...)* you can change **many existing partitions at once** using a single ALTER statement *(...)* Similar to dynamic partitioning, `hive.exec.dynamic.partition` must be set to true

Looks like the partial specification feature has been ported to other commands like DROP, TRUNCATE even if it's not explicit in the documentation.

In short: it's not a bug, it's a feature.

Comment: But if specify other column name it shouldn't drop all the partition, correct me If I am wrong. I have put the drop query in the question now.

Comment: Yes, indeed, if you have just 1 partition key and you specified a specific value for that key, Hive should have dropped that partition only. I have no idea of what happened in your case.