# Deleting partitions in impala dynamically

Tags: partitioning, impala

Impala allow to add partitions dynamically as following.

```
insert into table1 partition (part_col1="merged",part_col2,part_col3) 
select  col1,col2,col3,part_col2,part_col3 from table2 where 
col="SomeValue"
```

So it will add multiple partitions depending upon the results from the select query.But when it comes to dropping the partitions there does not seem to be equivalent. is there ? You have to explicitly specify partitions to be dropped.

```
alter table table1 drop 
partition(part_col1="A",part_col2="B",part_col3="C")
```

I can not just say something like

```
alter table table1 drop partition(part_col1="A",part_col2,part_col3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly No, there is no way to drop a partition dynamically as you specified in your example.

Comment: ...but it works with Hive, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32093132/hive-drops-all-the-partitions-if-the-partition-column-name-is-not-correct >> generally speaking there are many ALTER sub-commands that Impala does not support.

Answer (score 0):

Dropping multiple partitions is possible with Impala 2.8+

The documentation [states](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_alter_table.html) "In Impala 2.8 and higher, the expression for the partition clause with a DROP or SET operation can include comparison operators such as <, IN, or BETWEEN, and Boolean operators such as AND and OR."

For an example see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45550350/4202225 where the second Demo shows how to drop a range of partitions